# Drawing rectangles to the screen in WPF from another class

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

So I have a method in the main class that a class `Pillar`, which creates two rectangles and sets their width and height. I then try to draw them to the screen using `Canvas.SetTop`.

```
'Main

'place rectangles
Canvas.SetTop(pillar.top, 0)
Canvas.SetBottom(pillar.bottom, 0)

Canvas.SetLeft(pillar.top, 100)
Canvas.SetLeft(pillar.bottom, 100)
```

And here's the pillar class

```
Class Pillar
    Property Right As Integer
    Public top, bottom As Rectangle
    Private gap As Integer = 60
    Private _width = 100
    Private gapPos As Integer

    Public Sub New()
        top = New Rectangle
        bottom = New Rectangle

        top.Width = _width
        bottom.Width = _width

        gapPos = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 80)) + 470

        top.Height = gapPos - (gap / 2)
        bottom.Height = gapPos - (gap / 2)

        top.Fill = New SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255))
        bottom.Fill = New SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255))
    End Sub
End Class
```

The problem is the rectangles aren't being drawn the the screen, while the program throws no errors.

Comment: The problem is the rectangles aren't being drawn the the screen, while the program throws no errors.

Comment: You should edit that information into your question.

Comment: Did you add your rectangle to the PaintCanvas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Canvas.SetTop/Bottom/Left/Right()` doesn't draw something on the screen, but positions elements that are already shown on the screen. So, before calling

```
Canvas.SetTop(pillar.top, 0)
```

try to add the rectange to the canvas, for example by calling

```
myCanvas.Children.Add(pillar.top)
```

Comment: Thank you, completely forgot to add to the canvas